# prevent element from wrapping around floating sibling element

Tags: html, css

i want *content* **NOT to wrap around it's floating sibling** (may it be floating on content's left or right).

there will be no content following the content so **containing floats/realigning baselines is out of the question**. i just want content to "stand up and not curl around"

i know this is easily done by putting `overflow:auto/hidden` on the content - done it many times. however, this time, i cannot because.

- the content will contain an `<ul>` of inherited width and *has box-shadow* - content will clip shadows if it has `overflow:auto/hidden`
- i cannot set padding to the sides of `<ul>` because it has to be the same width as content.
- i must NOT explicitly set dimensions, paddings and margins in any unit of measure, the same way when i do it when putting `overflow:auto/hidden`. this includes (but not limited to) adding a margin to move the wrap away from the floating element - the floating element's content may be dynamic in width.

my html and css is here: http://jsfiddle.net/QQQB5/2/ - but this one uses `overflow` to prevent wrapping but clips the shadows.

is there any other way to prevent *content* from wrapping aside from using `overflow`? as much as possible, no hacks, no "tricks/cheats". additional mark-up accepted if it can't be avoided.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure where you want your content to be. Did you try playing with clear:left/right/both ?

Comment: i have tried the `<div style="clear:both" />` already. adds too much unnecessary mark-up.

Comment: unecessary markup ? if it's what it takes to solve your problem, that's not what I'd call unecessary markup ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `float:left` on the content container as well and it will be fine :)

```
.content {zoom:1; float:left;}
```

#### Update:

Just because the link you provided which is from 2004 used FNE this isn't the case nowadays.

With CSS3 you just add:

```
.container:after { 
      content: "";
      display: block;
      clear: both;
 }
```

and you don't float everything.

Comment: that's the FnE (Float nearly Everything) method. it only solves clearing, not the wrapping. http://orderedlist.com/blog/articles/clearing-floats-the-fne-method/

Comment: still, that's a clearfix in your update. http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack/ - this might be 3 years old but still makes perfect sense

Comment: @fskreuz Of course, i know this is a clearfix. Do you suggest that we don't use contained floats just because they need to be cleared in order for their containers to expand correctly?

Comment: the idea of the question was to *avoid the wrapping around the float*. containing floats is another issue that is easily done by clearfix.

Comment: @fskreuz Hehe. Exactly that, by _floating your element that is wrapping_, _you avoid the wrapping around the float_. Whether a float should be clearfixed, what the best way of clearfixing is and other similars should be raised in other questions. Agreed? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without floats:

```
.floater, .content {display: inline-block;}
.floater {vertical-align: top;}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrgkT/)

Comment: already considered `inline-block` but content won't expand to fill in the remaining space. content's width depends on its contents for width